# C++ Visual Studio 2015 “non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member”

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com

I work with TaskScheduler COM, this is my code:

```cpp
typedef HRESULT(*FuncOfBoll)(_Out_ VARIANT_BOOL* b);

static bool GetBool(FuncOfBoll func)
{
    VARIANT_BOOL b = VARIANT_FALSE;
    HRESULT hr = func(&b);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return FALSE;
    return b == VARIANT_TRUE;
}

void test(ITaskSettings* settings)
{
    bool b = GetBool(settings->get_StopIfGoingOnBatteries); // <= The error here
    // ...
}
```

and I get the following error:

> Error C3867   'ITaskSettings::get_StopIfGoingOnBatteries': non-standard
>   syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

What is my mistake and how to correct it?

Comment: @PeteBecker the parameter for that function (`GetBool`) is a function taking bool, which wont work with a member function.

Comment: You can't do that. Non-static class member functions aren't functions, e.g. they cannot be *called* like functions can be called.

Comment: Voted to close as **unclear what you're asking**. See [my comment-as-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39622968/464581) for some hopefully helpful commentary about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct definition for a pointer to **member** function is:

```
typedef HRESULT(ITaskSettings::*FuncOfBoll)(_Out_ VARIANT_BOOL* b);
```

Then, you should pass the pointer to the object instance to function `GetBool`:

```
static bool GetBool(ITaskSettings* setting, FuncOfBoll func)
{
    VARIANT_BOOL b = VARIANT_FALSE;
    HRESULT hr = (setting->*func)(&b);
    ...
}
```

Or, with template:

```
template<class C>
static bool GetBool(C* p, HRESULT(C::*func)(_Out_ VARIANT_BOOL*))
{
    VARIANT_BOOL b = VARIANT_FALSE;
    HRESULT hr = (p->*func)(&b);
    ...
}
```

Invocation:

```
void test(ITaskSettings* settings)
{
    currentSetttings = settings;
    bool b = GetBool(settings, &ITaskSettings::mb_function);
}
```

Comment: Even if you change that you can't call a member function without an instance.

Comment: @Borgleader : that's right; answer fixed (I hope with no mistake)

Comment: @shrike I get error `expected a member name` on this line: `setting->(*func)(&b);`

Comment: @shrike Excellent! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that `get_StopIfGoingOnBatteries` is a member function of`ITaskSettings`. Such a function cannot be used when the expected argument type is `FuncOfBoll`. You'll need to create a wrapper function and use it.

```
ITaskSettings* currentSetttings = NULL;

HRESULT GetBoolWrapper(_Out_ VARIANT_BOOL* b)
{
   return currentSetttings->get_StopIfGoingOnBatteries(b);
}

void test(ITaskSettings* settings)
{
   currentSetttings = settings;
   bool b = GetBool(GetBoolWrapper);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>This is not really an answer, the question as written doesn't admit an answer, but this is too long & detailed for comment.</sup>

You don't show a full examples, so there has to be **guesswork**.

Apparently, judging by the error message, `settings` is a pointer to class type object, where that class has a member function `get_StopIfGoingOnBatteries`.

And apparently, judging by the use of `->` operator, it's a non-`static` member function. You could still use `->` if it were `static`, but that would be unnatural. So let's say it's a non-`static` member function.

Then you can't easily form a raw pointer to function that calls that member function, because you need a `this`-pointer for the call. It could just use a dummy object, if creation of such object is cheap, or it could use a global instance or pointer to instance. But better change something in your design, and/or explain more clearly what you want.