# Use lambda as GLFWkeyfun

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

For one of my project, I am using GLFW3. And I am trying to give a C++11 lambda to the function [GLFWSetKeyCallback](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#ga7e496507126f35ea72f01b2e6ef6d155), who takes as parameters a GFLWwindow, and a GLFWfunkey function, which is a typedef to
void(* GLFWkeyfun) (GLFWwindow *, int, int, int, int).

The function is called from my Window class, here's the code

window.hpp

```
class Window
{
        public:
                Window(GLuint width, GLuint height, std::string title);
                ~Window();

                GLFWwindow* get() { return window_.get(); }
                bool is_open() { return open_; };
                void close();

        private:
                bool open_ = false;
                std::unique_ptr<GLFWwindow, DestroyWindow> window_;
                std::vector<Drawable*> drawables_;
};
```

And window.cpp

```
#include <pck/window.hpp>

Window::Window(GLuint width, GLuint height, std::string title) :
        open_(true)
{
        window_.reset(glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr));
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window_.get());

        Global::width = width;
        Global::height = height;

        glfwSetKeyCallback(window_.get(), [this](GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode){
                for(auto it : drawables_)
                        it->input(window, key, scancode, action, mode);
        });
}

Window::~Window()
{
        window_.reset();
}

void
Window::close()
{
        open_ = false;
        window_.reset();
}
```

And the error from the compiler (clang++ 3.8.1)

```
fatal error: no matching function for call to 'glfwSetKeyCallback'
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window_.get(), [this](GLFWwindow* window, i...
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h:3307:20: note: candidate function not viable: no
      known conversion from '(lambda at
      /path/to/file.cpp)' to
      'GLFWkeyfun' (aka 'void (*)(GLFWwindow *, int, int, int, int)') for 2nd argument
GLFWAPI GLFWkeyfun glfwSetKeyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, GLFWkeyfun cbfun);
```

Can somebody point me to what I did wrong please?

Thanks!

Comment: Might be helpful:http://stackoverflow.com/a/39622958/434551.

Answer (score 7):

As krzaq said you cannot use closures if your want a function pointer. So you must not capture `this` as in your example.

If you need `this` anyway, then you might associate it with your `GLFWwindow`. I see you can use this API: [glfwSetWindowUserPointer](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga3d2fc6026e690ab31a13f78bc9fd3651) to associate GLFWwindow instance with instance of your `Window` class. Then inside your callback you can retrieve it with: [glfwGetWindowUserPointer](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga17807ce0f45ac3f8bb50d6dcc59a4e06).

So your code would look like (pseudocode):

```
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window_.get(), this);
glfwSetKeyCallback(window_.get(), [](GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode){
                Window* pw = (Window*)glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
                for(auto it : pw->drawables_)
                        it->input(window, key, scancode, action, mode);
        });
```

Answer (score 7):

A lambda that has capture cannot be converted into a function pointer. A function pointer is stateless, it points to a function. A lambda with capture has a state. It behave like an object. A member function cannot be called without an instance. That's way a lambda with capture cannot be converted into function pointer.

You'll have to change your function to that:

```
glfwSetKeyCallback(window_.get(), [](GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode){ /* ... */ });
```

However, you can bypass this limitation of not being able to access this. GLFW given us a way to pass a state around. The struct `GLFWWindow` contains a `void*` member that you are free to change and access.

What you can do is something like this:

```
// Here we are setting the user pointer to `this`
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window_.get(), this);

glfwSetKeyCallback(window_.get(), [](GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode){
    // Here we retrieve the pointer we setted before. It will be equal to `this`
    auto& self = *static_cast<Window*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window));
    for(auto&& it : self.drawables_) {
        it->input(window, key, scancode, action, mode);
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks good, but the class `Window` is a wrapper aroud the GLFWwindow class, so I don't think this will work

Comment: What's the matter? You can put any object inside the user pointer. Including your own, and including your wrapper. It will not copy it. It will simply assign the pointer to your actual `this`. The user pointer exist exclusively for that purpose; setting a pointer so you can access an external state. That state happen to be your wrapper in your case.

Comment: I saw the doc, thanks. I'll try that later and give you a feedback

Answer (score 4):

Only lambdas with empty capture-list are convertible to plain old function pointers.

So, the problem is

```
[this]
```

instead of

```
[]
```

But if you need a stateful callback, then you're out of luck. As far as I can tell, this is not possible, not without evil gymnastics anyway.

That being said, most C APIs provide a context pointer allowing the callback to actually receive the state it's supposed to work on. It seems that the `window` parameter is that in your example.

Comment: I kind of hide the code in my lambda, but long story short, the function call is inside a class and I need `this` for what I'm doing in the lambda

Comment: I admit I don't know GLFW3, but the usual way it to provide a `context` parameter to the callback function, so that it could use the context while still being a free function (or a lambda disguised as a pointer to free function). Is the `window` parameter not it?

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne If you really need a capture list, then you simply can't use lambdas as callback to C functions.